# How to make a class act as another one

Tags: c#, data-structures

For structure reasons I have to make my file managing class `FileManagement` non-static.
Therefore I have to use it like this

```
FileManagement fm = new FileManagement();
fm.Save(10);
```

But I would like to use it statically, like

```
FileManagement.Save(10);
```

Now, I thought of creating an extra class like

```
public static class FileManager
{
    public static FileManagement Execute = new FileManagement();
}
```

Now I can do `Filemanager.Execute.Save(10);`

But is there a way, to make `FileManager` act completely like `FileManagement`?
So, that I could use it like `FileManager.Save(10);`?

Comment: Make static methods available in the class, perhaps?

Comment: Why do you want to use it like that? `Static` instances are for many considered to be harmful.

Comment: `Static instances are for many considered to be harmful.` Sorry but who are those many and why? Just curious

Comment: One word: threading.

Comment: It's because it introduces global state, and often will make testing between difficult and impossible. And as Nathan points out, threading becomes a nightmare.

Comment: And furthermore access management becomes a nightmare. Note that you have an additional access barrier because an instance has only access to another instance given it has a reference to it. Static circumvents this barrier by providing a globally accessible set of instances. Many security researchers therefore vote against `static`. Finally there is always the possibility as @AlexanderBrevig pointed out, that the state should not be global.

Comment: @Tim, the `FileManager` implements from `IFileManager`, which has no static methods. @Nathan, could you please elaborate?

Comment: While I admit the disadvantages static members/methods bring with them, but think about it for a moment. The Math class has lots of static methods in it. Assume we need the Round method. If no static methods, then we would have to either create an instance of that class with huge information for just one method, or to avoid wasting unnecessarily big space in the heap we would have to dissect this Math class into as many little parts as we could, like a separate class for Round, Abs, Sin etc.

Comment: That's because they aren't actually static methods in the real sense. These are *the instruction set*. The addition (`+`) operator is in C# a static method as well. But they are immediately translated to instructions. The problem is that the OO paradigm has no built-in instructions in contrast to for instance lambda-calculus. But I agree in such cases, one can use a static method. From the moment there is a state involved (like when one implements a `Save` method), one should use classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a static wrapper:

```
public static class FileManagementWrapper {
  private static readonly FileManagement execute = new FileManagement();

  public static void Save(int i) {
    execute.Save(i);
  }

  // other methods...
}
```

Comment: That would take a lot of time in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
public static class FileManager
{
    public static void Save(int arg){
        execute.Save(arg);
    }
    private static FileManagement execute = new FileManagement();
}
```

Comment: If you only delegate methods from FileManagement to the FileManager, then you should concider inheriting both from an interface. As long as you do not introduce other memebers in the FileManager then I think the static design is OK, as you can unit test your FileManagement class.